# Таймер в телеграм боте. Pytelegrambotapi

Tags: python, время

Пишу реализацию бота где, пользователь задаёт время, например 1 или 2 часа и, допустим по команде /status получает остаток времени в формате чч:мм. Использую библиотеку pytelegrambotapi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В простейшем случае Вам подойдёт модуль [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime).

Получите от пользователя задержку для таймера. Создайте на её основе объект [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) и добавьте к текущему времени. По запросу вычтите из полученной даты текущее время и выведите разницу в нужном формате.

***Пример:***

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

d = {'hours': 2}
end = datetime.now() + timedelta(**d)

# 1.5 hours later
curr = datetime.now()

diff = int((end - curr).total_seconds())
if diff > 0:
    hours, remainder = divmod(diff, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
else:
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0

print(f'{hours:02}:{minutes:02}')
```

***stdout:***

```py
00:30
```